# Can i use tor relay with 2 ip adresses?

Tags: configuration, relays, network-configuration

Can i use tor relay  with 2 ip adresses ?
I have 2 ip's on the same computer can i set both to same relay somehow?

Regards kof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both IP addresses. Best is to set up two different `torrc` files and start two processes. If you use Debian, there is a multi-instance systemd service file. Just create `/etc/tor/instances/1/torrc` and `/etc/tor/instances/2/torrc`. Now you can enable the services:

```
systemctl enable tor@1.service
systemctl enable tor@2.service
```

When you start Tor with `systemctl start tor`, systemd will take care about the start of both services.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. Tor won't use them both in teaming or load-balancing, but you can utilize via ORPort and DirPort directives values like `address:port` a different binding. Also you can use OutboundBindAddress to specify whic one will be used for primary traffic.

Comment: Dont i need 2x relays then?

Comment: What is your goal? To use both ISP lines simultaniously?